# How to combine iteration of two @objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I incorporate `<% @notes.each do |note| %>` into `@challenge.dates_challenged.first(@challenge.days_challenged).each_with_index do |date, i| %>` so that the conditional in challenges/show works?

Because right now the notes/form is being rendered multiple times per number of notes.

**challenges/show**

```
<% @challenge.dates_challenged.first(@challenge.days_challenged).each_with_index do |date, i| %>
  <% @notes.each do |note| %> # How to incorporate this iteration into above iteration?
    Day <%= i + 1 %>
    <% if note.notes_date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") == date.strftime("%m/%d/%y") %> # If note is created on date then show note else show form
      <%= note.notes_text %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'notes/form', :date => date %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is because there is two iterations instead of combining the two. I don't know how to combine the two so that the iteration works where if a note is created on a `date` then show `<%= note.notes_text %>` else show notes/form.

Comment: How is your Note model associated with your date? It's not clear why you're comparing two formatted dates, as comparing a Date to a Date should be sufficient.

Comment: I'm comparing `notes_date` to `date` because `notes_date` is an attribute of  `Note` whereas `date` is derived from the attribute of `days_challenged` from `Challenge` @tadman. I want to show a note or note/form for each day of a user's challenge. If the note is created for that day then the note should show otherwise the note/form should show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to line up two different data structures in Ruby you have a lot of tools at your disposal. One of the more convenient ones is being able to convert a list of things into a dictionary, a Hash, where you can quickly look them up by some arbitrary attribute.

For example:

```
<%- notes_for_date = @notes.group_by(&:note_date) -%>
```

Then you can display notes on any given date:

```
<%- if notes_for_date[date].any? %> 
  <%- notes_for_date[date].each do |note| -%>
    <%= note.notes_text %>
  <%- end -%>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'notes/form', :date => date %>
<% end %>
```

One thing you seem to be a little fuzzy on is that collections like `@notes` are an array or array-like structure where calling methods like `note_text` directly is not possible.

If you want to get all of those values you can do this:

```
note_texts = @notes.collect(&:note_text).join
```

That has the effect of pulling out all of the notes and combining them into a single string.

The thing to try and master first in Ruby when learning it is understanding how to transform the data you have into the form you need it in, or a form closer to the way you ultimately need it and tackle it step by step. The [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html) library is full of very handy tools and I'd encourage you to look through that in any free time you have to get a sense of the breadth and depth of the tools available.

Comment: Thanks again Tadman! I've been playing with your answer, but where do you get `[date]` from? Am I suppose to leave `<% @challenge.dates_challenged.first(@challenge.days_challenged).each_with_index do |date, i| %>` in because then that leads to `undefined method 'any?' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: You could `notes_for_date.each |date, notes|` to iterate over the dates.

Comment: `<% @notes_for_date.each do |date, notes| %>
    <% if @notes_for_date[date].any? %> 
      <% @notes_for_date[date].each do |note| %>
        <%= note.notes_text %>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'notes/form', :date => date %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>` so like that? And then I put `@notes_for_date = @notes.group_by(&:notes_date)` in the controller. That now makes all the forms go away if just one note is present